# Database only saving to debug folder

Tags: .net

I have a program this is saving data to a Access database. The code for saving to the database is:

```
Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\phipnasw01\users-hip$\cerns1\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Forte Data Gatherer\Forte Data Gatherer\Example1.accdb"
Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)

'Getting the character count for all variables.
GlobalVariables.mdbProdDate = Mid(GlobalVariables.stAddRec, 2, 19)
GlobalVariables.mdbBaleLine = Mid(GlobalVariables.stAddRec, 21, 3)
GlobalVariables.mdbBaleNumber = Mid(GlobalVariables.stAddRec, 33, 12)
GlobalVariables.mdbGrossWeight = Mid(GlobalVariables.stAddRec, 46, 6)
GlobalVariables.mdbAirDry = Mid(GlobalVariables.stAddRec, 53, 7)
GlobalVariables.mdbInvoiceWeight = Mid(GlobalVariables.stAddRec, 60, 8)

cnn.Open()

'Naming the new Row in Query1.
Dim newQuery1Row As Example1DataSet1.Query1Row
newQuery1Row = Me.Example1DataSet1.Query1.NewQuery1Row()

'Making the first row the date.
newQuery1Row.ProdDate = GlobalVariables.mdbProdDate
newQuery1Row.BaleLine = GlobalVariables.mdbBaleLine
newQuery1Row.BaleNumber = GlobalVariables.mdbBaleNumber
newQuery1Row.GrossWeight = GlobalVariables.mdbGrossWeight
newQuery1Row.AirDry = GlobalVariables.mdbAirDry
newQuery1Row.InvoiceWeight = GlobalVariables.mdbInvoiceWeight

'Adding the row to the table.
Me.Example1DataSet1.Query1.Rows.Add(newQuery1Row)

cnn.Close()

'Saving the row in Access.
Me.Query1TableAdapter.Update(Me.Example1DataSet1.Query1)
```

After the code runs the program saves the files correctly to the access database in the debug folder only. I need the database to save to the access database in C:\Forte\Example1.accdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;**Data Source=\\phipnasw01\users-hip$\cerns1\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Forte Data Gatherer\Forte Data Gatherer\Example1.accdb**"

The path is right there in the connection string, you hard coded it in. Just create the string at run-time using a [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) or something to save wherever you want.